# Loop to make grid of NSButtons?

Tags: objective-c, macos, loops, tags, nsbutton

I am trying to loop through and programmatically make a grid of 256 NSButtons (16x16). The code I have so far is below. This is in Objective-C for my Mac app. So I am logging to see which tag I get when I click a button, but it keep returning the same tag every time.

I want it so that every button goes 1-256 from left to right, top to bottom. This code successfully makes them load into my view, but the tags are wrong.

```
    #define N_ROWS  16
    #define N_COLS  16
    int btnSpaceDifference = 1;
    int btnSpacing = N_ROWS + btnSpaceDifference;

    for (int j = 0; j < N_ROWS; j++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < N_COLS; i++) {
            paintPixel = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10 + (i * btnSpacing), 10 + (j * btnSpacing), 16, 16)] autorelease];
            [paintPixel setTitle:@""];
            [paintPixel setBezelStyle:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
            [paintPixel setTag:j + i * N_ROWS + 1];
            [paintPixel setAction:@selector(btnPaintAction:)];
            [[[box.tabViewItems objectAtIndex:0]view] addSubview:paintPixel];
        }
    }

-(void)btnPaintAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%ld", paintPixel.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how its compiling, you might have *paintPixel* defined elsewhere. But you need to change your ***btnPaintAction*** from:

```
-(void)btnPaintAction:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"%ld", paintPixel.tag);
}
```

To something like this:

```
-(void)btnPaintAction:(id)sender {
     NSButton * myButton = (NSButton *) sender;
     NSLog(@"%ld", myButton.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making all of these buttons yourself, why not use an [`NSMatrix`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?  This is the sort of thing it's *perfect* for.

Answer (score 1):

call `setTag` with an increment variable

```
int TagVal = 1;

for (int j = 0; j < N_ROWS; j++) {
    ....
    [paintPixel setTag:TagVal++];
    ....
}
```

Then modify your btnPaintAction:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"%ld", button.tag);
```

Comment: bummer, beat the accepted answer by 18 minutes and still wasn't good enough

Answer (score 1):

It's returning the same tag every time because your action is referring to your (apparently) member variable `paintPixel`.  Use the `sender` parameter to the action instead.

```
NSLog(@"%ld", ((NSButton *)sender).tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old post but I see no correct answer, thus my addition.

Q. " I want it so that every button goes 1-256 from left to right, top to bottom."

Kevin was on the good track, however one more alteration is required:

```
paintPixel = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10 + (i * btnSpacing), 10 - (j * btnSpacing), 16, 16)] autorelease];
```

Thus minus(-) instead of plus(+) results in numbering top to bottom.